PCA analog when points are SPD matrices and congruence instead of linear projection
Let's consider the following formulation of PCA. We have a set of points $\{x_1, ..., x_m\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and a function $L_{\mathbf{V}}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$, with $k < n$, where $L_{\mathbf{V}}(x_i)= \mathbf{V}^Tx_i = y_i$. $\mathbf{V} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ is constrained to have orthonormal columns $\mathbf{v}_j$. PCA finds the set of column vectors $\mathbf{v}_j$, such that the variance of the projected points $\{y_1\, .., y_m\}$ is maximized, which is equivalent to maximizing the sum of the squared pairwise distances between all pairs of points $\sum_i \sum_j \|y_i - y_j \|^2$.
Now consider the following analogous problem. The points $\{X_1, ..., X_m\}$ are symmetric positive definite matrices, i.e. they are in the $\mathbb{S}^+_n$ manifold. The function $L_{\mathbf{V}}: \mathbb{S}^+_n \to \mathbb{S}^+_k$ that reduces the dimensionality of points $X$ is now given by $L_{\mathbf{V}}(X_i) = \mathbf{V}^T X_i \mathbf{V} = Y_i$. We also want to find the matrix $\mathbf{V}$ with orthonormal columns (i.e. the matrix is in the Stiefeld manifold) that maximizes the pairwise squared distances between the set of points $\{Y_1, ... Y_m\}$. However, we use distances defined on the SPD manifold, particularly the Affine Invariante distance $d(A,B)=\| \log (A^{-1/2} B A^{-1/2})\|^2_F$ or the log-euclidean distance $d(A,B)^2=\| \log(A) - \log(B)\|^2_F$.
My question is, since these two formulations look so similar, whether this is some kind of known problem. I am particularly interested in eventually obtaining some algorithm to find $\mathbf{V}$. Also on the case where the columns of $\mathbf{V}$ are constrained to be unit vectors, but not orthogonal.
As a side question, I know that if $\mathbf{V}$ is invertible, then $Y_i = \mathbf{V}^T X_i \mathbf{V}$ is called a conjugate transformation. Is there a name or anything interesting to be said when $\mathbf{V}$ is rectangular such as here? (this has been asked before, and is unanswered).

I found that almost this exact formulation is previously described in the literature, in the article "Geometry-aware principal component analysis for symmetric positive definite matrices". The one small difference that I can see with the formulation in the question is that the authors don't maximize the pairwise distances between points $Y_i$, but the distances from each point $Y_i$ to an approximated mean $\hat{Y}$. While these two approaches are the same in the Euclidean case, they are not the same in general when $Y_i$ are points on a manifold. The authors use standard algorithms for optimization in manifolds to optimize $\mathbf{V}$ in the Grassmanian manifold.
